# JavaFX / TornadoFX cause Keystroke Receiving prompt on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: java, javafx, tornadofx, macos-catalina

**Problem description**

I have the a problem with JavaFX and TornadoFX.
When I start my application on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina), the following error message appears:

> **Keystroke Receiving**
>
> "yourapplication" would like to receive keystrokes from any
>   application.
>
> Grant access to this application in Security & Privacy preferences,
>   located in System Preferences.

I see this error message with any JavaFX and TornadoFX application I create. No matter how simple it is.

Is there some way to make this message disappear? I do not want to release the software when it shows this prompt.

**Environment**

- TornadoFX 1.7.18
- Java 8 / JavaFX8
- Catalina Beta 9 (19A573a)

I also tried other versions like JavaFX13 and TornadoFX 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, but I saw the same prompt.

**Maybe related to this:**

- https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/macos-10-15-new-permission-prompts/26251

**Edit**

Bug Report in Orcale JIRA: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231513

Comment: Yep, I also created a basic JavaFX app (Oracle Java SDK 8) using IntelliJ Idea on Catalina Beta 9 (19A573a) - and even that very basic standard project causes same issue: when I try to start it, I see a popup saying that `"IntelliJ IDEA" would like to receive keystrokes from any application`. Would be really interesting to find out a solution for this.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, mipa. I did it now.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in openjfx14. (according to bug ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231513)